# Tips for creating an admin login for a client's website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, web, administration

I'm creating a website for a real estate firm. Looking great, but the last component is to create an admin login for my client so he can login and add/remove real estate properties he has to sell. I plan to store his entries in a database file. The entries will be displayed in a web control on a public page which will be bound to the DB.

How do I best create a login considering it is an ASP.NET 3.5 website? I do not [yet] know PHP, and I read some MSDN stuff on creating roles & members and it seemed like a bit much considering I just want one admin login for my client.

Any tips, recommendations?

Comment: I couldn't get the asp.net security console to connect to the sql provider. Spent hours trying to figure out why it couldn't create an instance. After much researching, turns out to be a bug in sqlserver express which causes it to crap out if there was once a previous installation of sql server. Had to delete a hidden version in the local settings folder! 

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/sqldatabaseengine/thread/f5eb164d-9774-4864-ae05-cac99740949b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make a membership provider, you can use the standard login-controls that are included in the toolbox!

check out this:  http://www.devx.com/asp/Article/29256 and this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx .  Then, check out this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx for how to use the login control.

Answer (score 1):

Create a login table with validation functions (DON'T store passwords in plain-text - use md5)

Add a login control on a backend page where you expect him to log in.

Around "Admin" type functionality create an "IsLoggedIn()" function that only displays admin stuff if the user is logged in.

You might want to verify with the client that the only login type will be an admin login type so that you don't have to go back later and redo everything with account types and other privileges and such.